# Is the list of words that get elided a closed set?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, élision

In the following Wikipedia article, it lists many words that get elided.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision_(French)

- le, la
- je, ce
- me, te, se
- moi, toi
- ne
- de
- que
- si

However, it doesn't say if this is a closed set. In other words, is this the complete list or are there other words that get elided too?

The article also mentions that in informal speech but not in writing that *tu* commonly gets elided to *t'es* and *t'as*.

Comment: Do you have any exampler where "moi" and "toi" are elided ? I can't see any...

Comment: @Random Wikipedia lists _Mettez-**le**, donne-les-**moi**, casse-**toi**_ -> _Mettez-**l**'y, donne-**m**'en, va-**t**'en_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other conjunctions which end in *-que* should be added to the list : *puisque*, *lorsque*, *quoique*.

Elided forms of *entre* and *presque* are sometimes used as a prefix. For example, in *entr'apercevoir* (old orthography), or *presqu'ile*. Some authors [chose to elide](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/presque) other uses of *presque*.

*Jusque* and *quelque* are also elided in front of a vowel, but the list does not extend much further.

Comment: Thanks! I just found this answer on a similar (but not duplicate) question which almost answers my question: http://french.stackexchange.com/a/13308/6454. You have included _presque_ which is missing from the other answer.