# When to use "s' " and "se"

Tags: grammaire, élision

When using reflexive verbs, is there any hint whether to use the prefix *s'* or *se*? For example: s'aimble and se laver

Comment: What is "s'aimble" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't “tu es” written “t'es”?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13303/why-isnt-tu-es-written-tes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules are those of [elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision_(French)).

The final 'e' of 'se' is replaced by an apostrophe when the following word starts with a vowel or a mute 'h'.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is : before a vowel remove the [ə]

*aimer*: **s'** aimer

*perdre*: **se** perdre

...