# Why does "Je t'aime" have an elision whereas "Tu es bête" has no elision?

Tags: pronoms, élision

So we'll go with the translations.

> Tu es bête → You are stupid.
>
> Je t'aime → I love you.

There is an elision in "Je t'aime", while "tu" is spelled in full in "Tu es". Why is the first one elided?

I'm sorry if there is something obvious- I'm only learning!

Comment: @Stéphanegimenez I'm asking about "Je t'aime", not "Tu es."

Comment: Ok the phrasing was a bit weird so I misunderstood your problem. I tried to improve it.

Comment: K, sorry for the *idée fausse.*

Comment: Hint: I and me. You and you. He and him. She and her. We and us…

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't “tu es” written “t'es”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13303/why-isnt-tu-es-written-tes?rq=1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using direct object pronouns that end with a vowel:

> me
>
> te ----> **(NOT "tu")**
>
> le
>
> la

there should always be an elision.

The reason "Tu es bête" is not written (at least formally) "T'es bête" is because it is constructed with the subject pronoun *Tu* + verb.

You would never write (again, formally or academically):

> T'envoies une lettre à... ?

or

> T'oses faire ça...

because these are examples of where "Tu" is the subject, but you could say

> Il **t'**envoie une lettre...

or

> On ose **te** faire ça...

because here, "te" is the direct object pronoun and sometimes requires an elision.