# "L'histoire tout entière" or "l'histoire toute entière"

Tags: accord, adverbes

> Je trouvais l'histoire **tout entière** incroyable.
>
> OR: Je trouvais l'histoire **toute entière** incroyable.

In the case of the phrase "haut placé", I understand that just the "placé" part should agree with the preceding feminine noun, with the "haut" never changing into "haute(s)":

> certaines personnes **haut placées**
>
> NOT: certaines personnes **hautes placées**

I wonder if the same goes for the phrase "tout entier". Should just the "entier" part change into "entière", with the "tout" invariably staying the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les règles d'accord des adverbes **haut** et **tout**, placés devant un adjectif, sont différentes.

**Haut**,  adverbe placé devant un adjectif, est toujours invariable.

> Ces personnes sont haut placées.

La règle d'accord de **tout adverbe** placé devant un adjectif est :

**Tout**, adverbe, est invariable sauf quand il est placé devant un adjectif féminin **commençant par une consonne ou un h aspiré**, ceci pour des raisons d'**euphonie**.

Donc :

- l'histoire **tout entière** est incroyable (Adjectif commençant par une voyelle.)
- Elles étaient **toutes honteuses** d'avoir oublié l'heure. (Adjectif féminin commençant par un h aspiré : accord.)
- Elles étaient **toutes contentes** de leur réussite. (Adjectif féminin commençant par une consonne : accord.)
- Ils étaient **tout honteux** d'avoir oublié l'heure. (Adjectif masculin, pas d'accord.)
- Elles étaient **tout heureuses** de me voir arriver si tôt. (Adjectif commençant par un h muet : pas d'accord.)

**Attention** à  :

> Elles étaient toutes honteuses d'avoir oublié l'heure.
>   Elles étaient toutes contentes de leur réussite.

où à l'écrit *toutes* peut se comprendre comme un pronom (→ chacune d'entre elles) ou comme un adverbe (toutes modifiant l'adjectif). Le contexte permet en général d'éclairer.

À l'oral la diction des deux cas est différente.
Dans le cas où *toutes* est employé comme pronom le mot est accentué (accent tonique de fin de groupe de souffle) et on marque un bref arrêt après *toutes*. Dans le cas où *toutes* est employé comme adverbe, non seulement le mot n'est pas accentué et on ne marque pas le léger arrêt mais dans le cas d'un h aspiré certains vont même faire une liaison : /tutɔ̃tøz/ (toutes honteuses).

**Historique** de la règle : en ancien français, *tout* (comme tous les adjectifs employés comme adverbes) s'accordaient **dans tous les cas**. La règle observée aujourd'hui a été élaborée dans ses grandes lignes [par Vaugelas](https://books.google.fr/books?id=GybEMOT_zTMC&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=r%C3%A8gle%20accord%20tout%20vaugelas&source=bl&ots=wzlEQS7zBW&sig=u7oGlB7kbtmZ1b6T4JKHlj1ZN5A&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX1PHutObOAhWFbBoKHfnzA8kQ6AEINTAE#v=onepage&q=r%C3%A8gle%20accord%20tout%20vaugelas&f=false) et [précisée peu après par l'Académie](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#88_strong-em-tout-tonne-mais-toute-surprise-em-strong).
Cette règle issue d'un compromis (voir les liens donnés ci-dessus) étant assez arbitraire ça explique les incertitudes de l'usage, innombrables au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle (voir Racine) et encore fréquents au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle (voir Balzac). De nos jours, la règle est établie et en dehors d'être ce que l'[Académie Française appelle « un bon auteur »](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#88_strong-em-tout-tonne-mais-toute-surprise-em-strong) que personne n'ira juger pour la qualité de sa langue [il est conseillé de la respecter](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=42274) dans un contexte où on sera évalué sur la correction de son expression écrite.

Comment: About your last sentence, you might add that there is no difference in spoken French with *Elles étaient toutes heureuses de me voir arriver si tôt* where *toutes* is not an adverb but an pronoun (i.e. *Toutes étaient heureuses...*).

Comment: To @Laure: The concept of "h aspiré/muet" is news to me. Do they split into the two categories according to  a certain rule or in a completely random fashion? By the way, do you think too that it will be better to split my another question into two separate threads, as pointed out? I wasn’t sure if it’s a good idea to create two threads when one can easily contain two (rather simple) questions. Merci.

Comment: @LUNA An [excellent answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/1834/358) about h muet /h aspiré. Couldn't do better. Will leave you a message in chat for the rest.

Comment: @jlliagre je ne suis pas sûre de comprendre. Je sais que la liaison n'est pas obligatoire mais moi je la ferais spontanément justement pour lever  ambiguïté. L'ambiguïté à l'oral n'existe que devant une consonne ou un h aspiré, et encore l'intonation serait différente.

Comment: Addition to the rule described by Laure -- Note that it's sometimes ambiguous: *elles sont toutes contentes* can mean *they are very happy* (adverb) or *they are all happy/all of them are happy* (adjective). So it would be: *elles sont tout étonnées* (adverb) and *elles sont toutes étonnées* (adjective). You could even write *elles sont toutes tout étonnées*.

Answer (score 2):

Both forms are generally accepted in the first case.

Despite being an adverb, *[tout](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tout)* becomes *toute* when followed by a feminine adjective starting with a consonant or a non mute h.

When the adjective starts with a vowel, the rule since the end of the 17th century is to stay invariable but *tout* might still optionally agree with the adjective like it used to do in the past. e.g. from the [Littré](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/littre/tout):

> Et puisque vous voyez mon âme toute entière.... *[Corneille, Nicom. III, 2]*
>
> D'un repas sortant toute enfumée, *[Boileau, Sat. X]*

This final -e is controversial, some dictionaries no more mention its possibility.

**Edit**: The final -e is actually considered to be a mistake nowadays. I stand corrected by Laure.

<sub>Quite an absurd/inconsistent grammatical rule IMHO...</sub>

Comment: Si l'usage fut flottant jusqu'au 19s. (pour des raisons historiques que je peux donner si ça intéresse quelqu'un) l'accord devant une voyelle ou un h muet n'est plus admis de nos jours et par honnêteté vis à vis des non francophones il faut leur dire qu'il serait compté comme une erreur dans un examen.

Comment: @Laure Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this sentence, *tout* is an adverb. Adverbs are invariable. So :

> Je trouvais l'histoire **tout entière** incroyable.

Comment: Regarding the phrase "haut placé", the "haut{highly}" is an adverb and the "placé{placed}" is an adjective. So only the adjective "placé" should be affected, correct? Merci.

Comment: @LUNA Yes, correct.